# Use transactions PublishKafka_2_0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am using the next configuration of the Publish Kafka processor:

[image]
Edited kafka and zookeeper config:

```
zookeeper.properties

authProvider.sasl=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
```

```
zookeeper_jaas.conf

Server {
org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   user_super="zookeeper"
   user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

```
server.properties

security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
auto.create.topics.enable=false
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://172.23.199.20:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://172.23.199.20:9092
zookeeper.set.acl=true
super.users=User:admin
```

```
kafka_server_jaas.conf

KafkaServer {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
username="admin"
password="admin-secret"
user_admin="admin-secret";
};
Client {
org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
username="admin"
password="admin-secret";
};
```

Authentication works fine.

Enabling authorization

Add admin:

```
./bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=admin-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name admin
```

Add user:

```
./bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=123456]' --entity-type users --entity-name pkalita
```

Add permission:

```
./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:admin --producer --topic test
```

```
./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:pkalita --producer --topic test
```

After these actions processor PublishKafka works fine with principal admin but throw an exception if choose a user pkalita:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TransactionalIdAuthorizationException: Transactional Id authorization failed
```

[image]
The processor works if only set Use transactions - false

What I am doing wrong?

upd:
I tried to send a message using spring Kafka producer with the user pkalita - the message was published on the topic successfully

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the transactional ID when setting ACLs.

From the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authorization.html#enabling-authorization-for-idempotent-and-transactional-apis):

> The principal used by transactional producers must be authorized for Describe and Write operations on the configured `transactional.id`.

```
bin/kafka-acls --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --command-config adminclient-configs.conf \
 --add --allow-principal User:Alice \
 --producer --topic test-topic --transactional-id test-txn
```

You can also use `--transactional-id *` to allow any transactional ID.

Comment: thx, I see this command, but I didn't find what should be in adminclient-configs.conf file?

Comment: that file can contain configs for the admin client (e.g. SASL or SSL configuration). You probably don't need it, just add the `--transactional-id` config, when setting ACLs for pkalita user